# iterating or reading javascript object in python

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

I am trying to work with a javascript object, which is an array in this case, in my python code. I am able to get the array into my python code from javascript but when I try to parse array using

`for key in array:` format, but i am unable to loop through and get

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable.`

When i print the array i get a `[object Object]` on screen. What are the best methods to access or loop though this object in python?

Comment: The error message you get means that your variable array is None, so you didn't get the array into it.

Also, printing an object _in Javascript_ gives `[object Object]`, not Python.

So: how did you try to get the Javascript object into Python?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich So in my javascript code, i am building a multi-dimensional array using `var test = {}` and then adding to consecutively. When I call the js function in my python code, the js code returns me this above `test`. But then it's being returned as object and i want to iterate through this in my python code. That's the problem here.

Comment: {} is an object in Javascript, so that's why Javascript prints it as [object Object]. But _how_ are you calling the js function in your Python code? That's not something you can do normally. You need to show both your Javascript and your Python code.